# IdentityServer4 role based authorization correct use

Tags: c#, identityserver4, openid-connect, roles, claims

I'm currently working on a .net5.0 IdentityServer4 application.

I want to use role based authorization, unfortunately it seems not to work correctly.

When I use the `[Authorization]` attribute on my controller action, I can logon correctly.

When I use `[Authorize(Roles = "admin")]` attribute on my controller action, I get forwarded to the access denied page (403).

When I login with my TestUser with role admin, I get forwarded to the access denied page on my client app.

My application structure looks like this:

- IdentityServer4
- OIDC Client (Wen App, Authorization Code + PKCE)

The **IdentityServer4** Configuration looks like this:

```
public static IEnumerable<Client> GetClients()
{
    return new List<Client>
    {
        new Client
        {
            ClientId = "oidcClient",
            ClientName = "Example Client Application",
            ClientSecrets = new List<Secret> { new Secret("secret".Sha256()) },

            AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.Code,
            RedirectUris = new List<string> { "https://localhost:xxxx/signin-oidc" },
            AllowedScopes = new List<string>
            {
                IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
                IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile,
                IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Email,
                "role"
            },

            RequirePkce = true,
            AllowPlainTextPkce = false
        }
    };

public static IEnumerable<IdentityResource> GetIdentityResources()
{
    return new[]
    {
        new IdentityResources.OpenId(),
        new IdentityResources.Profile(),
        new IdentityResources.Email(),
        new IdentityResource
        {
            Name = "role",
            UserClaims = new List<string> { "role" }
        }
    };
}

public static List<TestUser> GetUsers()
{
    return new List<TestUser> {
        new TestUser {
            SubjectId = "123ABC",
            Username = "admin",
            Password = "password",
            Claims = new List<Claim> {
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email, "admin@test.com"),
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "admin")
            }
        }
    };
}
```

The Oidc connect configuration on my **client app** looks like this:

```
services.AddAuthentication(options => 
{
    options.DefaultScheme = "cookie";
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "oidc";
})
.AddCookie("cookie")
.AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", options => 
{
    options.Authority = "https://localhost:5000";
    options.ClientId = "oidcClient";
    options.ClientSecret = "secret";

    options.ResponseType = "code";
    options.UsePkce = true;
    options.ResponseMode = "query";

    // Edit 1
    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
       NameClaimType = ClaimTypes.Name,
       RoleClaimType = ClaimTypes.Role
    };

    options.SaveTokens = true;
});
```

My **controller** action is quite simple - only roles no policies yet - and looks like this:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "admin")] // Roles does not work
//[Authorize] works fine
public IActionResult Home()
{
    return View();
}
```

It feels like the access token is not passed to my client - only the idenity token...

Anyways, when I debug the action the User claims look like this:
[image]

I use an IdentityServer4 TestUser and I don't have an IProfileService implementation yet. Is it necessary?

Do you know how to solve this issue?

How can I use the role claim in my application correctly?

Comment: Could you show your authorization policies?

Comment: Thanks for your comment! I don't use policies yet - it's a simple starter with OIDC client. I only use the [Authorize(Roles = "admin")] attribute on my controller action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IdentityServer/OpenIDConnect and Microsoft have different opinions on what the name claim should be be called. So you need to tell your app what your role and name claim is called.

Like this:

```
}).AddOpenIdConnect(options =>
{
    ...
    
    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        NameClaimType = JwtClaimTypes.Name,
        RoleClaimType = JwtClaimTypes.Role,
    };

});
```

Comment: Thanks! To be independent from IdentityModel NuGet I will use ClaimTypes. Unfortunately I still got something wrong - I updated my question accordingly. Then do I need to use ClaimTypes in my ClientResource and IdentityResource and ApiResource as well?

Comment: to debug these kind of issues, always first start by looking inside the tokens, so make sure the role/name claims are provided in the token or from the userinfo endpoint.  You need to add the UserClaims to your IdentityResource that you want to have shown in the ID-token and UserClaims to the ApiResource  or ApiScope that you want to have added to the access token.

Comment: It's a good advice - but I haven't made it work yet unfortunately. Can you give me a hint, on how to debug the token please? Somehow I cannot see the token in Chrome because it is stored in an authentication cookie. I have the IdentityServer4 logging though.

Comment: It seems impossible to get the role claim to the client - maybe it's due to the IdentityServer4 TestUser class...

Comment: Use a tool like Fiddler to capture the raw HTTP(s) traffic (Don't forget to enable HTTPS) https://www.getfiddler.com/  then locate the token that starts with ey.... and then paste it into https://jwt.io to decode the token.

Comment: The UserClaims listed in the Resources then needs to have the same claim listed under in the TestUser. like adding new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.Role, "ceo"), to the user.

Comment: Thanks again. I need to mark your answer as correct!

Comment: It's all about the naming. In my case I had to add the Claim to the IProfileService implementation (probably TestUser...), in the Client definition I had to add "roles" instead of "role"... and AlwaysIncludeUserClaimsInIdToken = true

Comment: Actually there are 2 solutions: Claims from IdToken or Claims from UserEndpoint - as you described - your solution works perfectly when I add options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true; in my OIDC client - have a nice evening!!

Comment: Awsome! Glad you found the problem!